# Symfony 4 - Webpack Encore bootstrap css not in output

Tags: symfony, webpack, yarnpkg, webpack-4, webpack-encore

I am trying to introduce Webpack Encore into my Symfony 4 app to manage the JS & CSS assets.

I installed `yarn` and `nodejs`.

Then `composer require encore` and then `yarn install`.

I have the `app.js` file in `assets/js/`.

```
/*
 * Welcome to your app's main JavaScript file!
 *
 * We recommend including the built version of this JavaScript file
 * (and its CSS file) in your base layout (base.html.twig).
 */

// any CSS you require will output into a single css file (app.css in this case)
require('bootstrap');
require('../css/app.css');

// Need jQuery? Install it with "yarn add jquery", then uncomment to require it.
const $ = require('jquery');

console.log('Hello Webpack Encore! Edit me in assets/js/app.js');
```

Installed bootstrap and other dependencies with yarn:

```
{
    "devDependencies": {
        "@symfony/webpack-encore": "^0.22.0",
        "bootstrap": "^4.3.1",
        "jquery": "^3.3.1",
        "popper.js": "^1.14.7",
        "webpack-notifier": "^1.6.0"
    },
    "license": "UNLICENSED",
    "private": true,
    "scripts": {
        "dev-server": "encore dev-server",
        "dev": "encore dev",
        "watch": "encore dev --watch",
        "build": "encore production --progress"
    }
}
```

Then run `yarn encore dev --watch`

**Problem**

I do not get any bootstrap css in my `public/build/app.css`.

Do I need anything more than `require('bootstrap');` in `webpack.config.js`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you go to the `node_modules` directory, look for `bootstrap` and open its `package.json` you'll find the entry:

```
"main": "dist/js/bootstrap",
```

When you do:

```
require("bootstrap");
```

in your file you require the file(s) specified in the section `main` of the library's `package.json`.
You can however require any file from the library by specifying its (relative) path:

```
require("bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css");
```

Now you can run:

```
yarn encore dev
```

and the Bootstrap CSS should be in your `app.css`.

EDIT (2019-03-05):
Here is the [relevant block code](https://symfonycasts.com/screencast/webpack-encore/require-css#codeblock-8983811f58) of the screencast *7. Require CSS!?*, part of the SymfonyCasts Course [Webpack Encore: A Party for your Assets Tutorial](https://symfonycasts.com/screencast/webpack-encore).

**UPDATE** (2019-11-25):
This answer explains how to bind (import) a CSS library installed with `yarn` (or `npm`) using the `require` function provided by [Node.js](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_require_id).

ECMAScript 2015 (also known as ES6) introduces new feature `import`. Its usage is explained in the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54984242/3848833) from [WhiteRabbit](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7750700/whiterabbit).

Beside these two options, there is also a third possibility to import Bootstrap and that is by using `@import` directly in your own CSS file:

```
@import 'bootstrap';
```

This applies only when using **Webpack** and **Yarn** (or **NPM**). *Webpack Encore* is able to resolve the path and import the correspondent CSS file.

Answer (score 6):

According to the documentation [bootstrap in webpack encore](https://symfony.com/doc/current/frontend/encore/bootstrap.html)

In the webpack.config.js you can have

```
var Encore = require('@symfony/webpack-encore');

Encore
    // directory where compiled assets will be stored
    .setOutputPath('public/build/')
    // public path used by the web server to access the output path
    .setPublicPath('/build')
    // only needed for CDN's or sub-directory deploy
    //.setManifestKeyPrefix('build/')

    /*
     * ENTRY CONFIG
     *
     * Add 1 entry for each "page" of your app
     * (including one that's included on every page - e.g. "app")
     *
     * Each entry will result in one JavaScript file (e.g. app.js)
     * and one CSS file (e.g. app.css) if you JavaScript imports CSS.
     */
    .addEntry('app', './assets/js/app.js')

    .splitEntryChunks()
    // will require an extra script tag for runtime.js
    // but, you probably want this, unless you're building a single-page app
    .enableSingleRuntimeChunk()

    /*
     * FEATURE CONFIG
     *
     * Enable & configure other features below. For a full
     * list of features, see:
     * https://symfony.com/doc/current/frontend.html#adding-more-features
     */
    .cleanupOutputBeforeBuild()
    .enableBuildNotifications()
    .enableSourceMaps(!Encore.isProduction())
    // enables hashed filenames (e.g. app.abc123.css)
    .enableVersioning(Encore.isProduction())

    // enables Sass/SCSS support
    // .enableSassLoader()

    // uncomment if you use TypeScript
    //.enableTypeScriptLoader()

    // uncomment if you're having problems with a jQuery plugin
    .autoProvidejQuery()

    // uncomment if you use API Platform Admin (composer req api-admin)
    //.enableReactPreset()
    //.addEntry('admin', './assets/js/admin.js')
;

module.exports = Encore.getWebpackConfig();
```

And you install jquery, popper.js, bootstrap, font-awesome with this following command (if you are using npm and if you need font-awesome) :

```
npm install jquery --save-dev
npm install popper.js --save-dev
npm install bootstrap@4 --save-dev
npm install font-awesome --save-dev
```

In app.js, you can have :

```
/*
 * Welcome to your app's main JavaScript file!
 *
 * We recommend including the built version of this JavaScript file
 * (and its CSS file) in your base layout (base.html.twig).
 */

// any CSS you require will output into a single css file (app.css in this case)
require('../css/app.css');

// Need jQuery? Install it with "yarn add jquery", then uncomment to require it.
const $ = require('jquery');
import 'popper.js';
import 'bootstrap';
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css';
import 'font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css';

$(document).ready(function(){
    // Put your jquery code here.
});
```

In your template, you can do :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>title</title>
        {{ encore_entry_link_tags('app') }}  
    </head>
    <body>
         <div id="content_container"></div>

         {% block lib_javascripts %}
              {{ encore_entry_script_tags('app') }}
         {% endblock %}
         {% block javascripts %}{% endblock %}
    </body>
</html>
```

You can build and watch. In your project directory, you can do :

```
./node_modules/.bin/encore dev --watch
```

Comment: this answer is not perfect since it need to have symfony/webpack-encore-bundle to be installed wich is not y default

Answer (score 2):

Basicaly what cezar said, but I put it in an answer since a comment would make it unreadable:

```
import 'bootstrap';  // js-file
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css'; // css file
```

Not 100% sure but I think you also need to import Popper and Jquery manually:

```
import Popper from 'popper.js';
import $ from 'jquery';
```

Comment: Yes, it is a valid answer, not just a comment. It's an alternative for getting the CSS files. In CSS it has been possible to import other files since ever (at least since I know CSS). When using Webpack and Yarn I think it's better to `require` all modules.

Comment: This answer explains the `import` feature implemented in ES6 ([MDN web docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import)). In my previous comment I referred to `@import` ([MDN web docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import)). I apologise for the confusing.